# Batch files for Java

Tags: java, batch-file

In order to use a USB magstripe reader for accepting credit cards on a PC, my company uses Java on our web portal. In order to get the magstripe reader working properly, our Helpdesk has to guide customers through moving rxtxSerial.dll and RXTXcomm.jar files to the respective bin and lib\ext folders in Windows. We also have to add two URLs to the site exceptions list in the Java Control Panel. Both of these processes currently involve using the GUI and guiding our customers through doing this on their computers.

Java isn't really a strong suit for me. I am trying to create a batch file (with the .dll and .jar files in the same directory) that will automate both processes so that all a user has to do is run the batch file. However, I am running into a few problems that I'm not entirely prepared for.

1. I need to be able to have this file work for all possible installation paths of Java on the customer's computer. I am fine having a separate batch file for 32-but and 64-bit Java. However, not every customer has the jre8 folder in their "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java" directory. Sometimes instead of jre8, they will have something like jre1.8.0_31. I need the batch file to be able to account for these differences as well.
2. As far as my understanding goes, the sites.exceptions file is stored in a subdirectory contained within the user's directory. The problem is that I need to be able to create a batch file that will be able to locate the current user's directory as a part of the full file path. Furthermore, I'm not entirely clear on how to edit the sites.exceptions from the command prompt. I suppose I could have a pre-made exceptions file that gets copied over the the right directory (and naturally overriding any currently existing file).

I'm very new to the IT field, so I don't know if what I am asking is possible or if I'm explaining this right. I would really appreciate some help.

Comment: I think you can and should try to solve this without a Java program. You users may not have Java installed at all, or Java 7, or 6 - it seems your program, as planned, needs 8. - As for extending a file with a couple of lines: you can use `echo` with redirection (`>>`).

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help you. This program detects wheter Java is installed or not. It also detects which version of java etc.

```
    @echo off
    if "%OS%" == "Windows_NT" setlocal
    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    ::  Set JAVA_HOME or JRE_HOME     ::
    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    set JDKKeyName64=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit
    set JDKKeyName32=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit
    set JREKeyName64=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment
    set JREKeyName32=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment

    reg query "%JDKKeyName64%" /s
    if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 (
        echo .Could not find 32 bit or 64 bit JDK
        echo .Looking for 32 bit JDK on 64 bit machine
        goto FINDJDK32
    )
    set KeyName=%JDKKeyName64%
    goto JDKRUN

    :FINDJDK32
    reg query "%JDKKeyName32%" /s
    if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU  1 (
        echo .Could not find 32 bit JDK
        echo .Looking for 32 bit or 64 bit JRE
        goto FINDJRE64
    )
    set KeyName=%JDKKeyName32%
    goto JDKRUN

    :FINDJRE64
    reg query "%JREKeyName64%" /s
    if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 (
        echo .Could not find 32 bit or 64 bit JRE 
        echo .Looking for 32 bit JRE on 64 bit machine
        goto FINDJRE32
    )
    set KeyName=%JREKeyName64%
    goto JRERUN

    :FINDJRE32
    reg query "%JREKeyName32%" /s
    if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 (
        echo .Could not find 32 bit JRE
        echo .Could not set JAVA_HOME or JRE_HOME. Aborting
        goto ENDERROR
    )
    set KeyName=%JREKeyName32%
    goto JRERUN

    :JDKRUN
    echo.
    echo Using JDK
    set "CURRENT_DIR=%cd%"
    set "YOUR_PROGRAM_HOME_HERE=%CURRENT_DIR%"

    set Cmd=reg query "%KeyName%" /s
    for /f "tokens=2*" %%i in ('%Cmd% ^| find "JavaHome"') do set JAVA_HOME=%%j

    echo.
    echo Seems fine!
    echo Set JAVA_HOME : %JAVA_HOME%
    echo Set YOUR_PROGRAM_HOME_HERE : %YOUR_PROGRAM_HOME_HERE%
    echo.

    goto NEXT

    :JRERUN
    echo.
    echo [XAMPP]: Using JRE
    set "CURRENT_DIR=%cd%"
    set "YOUR_PROGRAM_HOME_HERE=%CURRENT_DIR%\tomcat"

    set Cmd=reg query "%KeyName%" /s
    for /f "tokens=2*" %%i in ('%Cmd% ^| find "JavaHome"') do set JRE_HOME=%%j

    echo.
    echo Seems fine!
    echo Set JRE_HOME : %JRE_HOME%
    echo Set YOUR_PROGRAM_HOME_HERE : %CATALINA_HOME%
    echo.

    :ENDERROR
    exit 1

    :NEXT

    echo Finding Java Version

    set Cmd=reg query "%KeyName%" /v CurrentVersion
    for /f "tokens=2*" %%i in ('%Cmd% ^| find "CurrentVersion"') do set CVERSION=%%j

    echo Java Version: %CVERSION%
    echo Starting Service Install...
    echo .

    rem ----------END JAVA SEARCH-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Now we've found the java HomeDirectory we can execute our packets trough java. We can use java trough cmd, so this should need to be easy.

Example of what we can do now:

```
rem Make sure prerequisite environment variables are set
if not "%JAVA_HOME%" == "" goto gotJdkHome
if not "%JRE_HOME%" == "" goto gotJreHome
echo Neither the JAVA_HOME nor the JRE_HOME environment variable is defined
echo Service will try to guess them from the registry.
goto runAsUser
:gotJreHome
if not exist "%JRE_HOME%\bin\java.exe" goto noJavaHome
if not exist "%JRE_HOME%\bin\javaw.exe" goto noJavaHome
goto runAsUser
:gotJdkHome
if not exist "%JAVA_HOME%\jre\bin\java.exe" goto noJavaHome
if not exist "%JAVA_HOME%\jre\bin\javaw.exe" goto noJavaHome
if not exist "%JAVA_HOME%\bin\javac.exe" goto noJavaHome
if not "%JRE_HOME%" == "" goto runAsUser
set "JRE_HOME=%JAVA_HOME%\jre"
goto runAsUser
:noJavaHome
echo The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly
echo This environment variable is needed to run this program
echo NB: JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE
goto end
```

> Here comes the **main code** that let's you run your java applet/program

```
:doInstall
rem Install the service
echo Installing the service '%SERVICE_NAME%' ...
echo Using PROGRAM_HOME:    "%YOUR_PROGRAM_HOME_HERE%"
echo Using JAVA_HOME:        "%JAVA_HOME%"
echo Using JRE_HOME:         "%JRE_HOME%"

rem Use the environment variables as an example
rem Each command line option is prefixed with PR_

set "PR_INSTALL=%EXECUTABLE%"

rem Add another jar or java file next to it with a semicolon. (still in the quotes)

set "PR_CLASSPATH=%YOUR_PROGRAM_HOME_HERE%\javawishprogram.jar;%YOUR_PROGRAM_HOME_HERE%\MaybeASecondoneIfYouwant.jar"
rem Set the server jvm from JAVA_HOME
set "PR_JVM=%JRE_HOME%\bin\server\jvm.dll"

rem Here you can go further on the JVM or not, you can map out your options.
if exist "%PR_JVM%" goto foundJvm

rem Set the client jvm from JAVA_HOME
set "PR_JVM=%JRE_HOME%\bin\client\jvm.dll"
if exist "%PR_JVM%" goto foundJvm
set PR_JVM=auto
:foundJvm
echo Using JVM:              "%PR_JVM%"
rem Here you're launching the main programme.
"%EXECUTABLE%" //IS//%SERVICE_NAME% --StartClass programJava.startup.Bootstrap --StartParams start --StopParams stop --Startup auto
```

> You can do even more with this. But I'll let it to your imagination.

I borowed this script from CATALINA
This is the full script:

***INGORE***

```
@echo off
rem Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
rem contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
rem this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
rem The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
rem (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
rem the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
rem
rem     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
rem
rem Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
rem distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
rem WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
rem See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
rem limitations under the License.

if "%OS%" == "Windows_NT" setlocal
rem ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
rem NT Service Install/Uninstall script
rem
rem Options
rem install                Install the service using Tomcat7 as service name.
rem                        Service is installed using default settings.
rem remove                 Remove the service from the System.
rem
rem name        (optional) If the second argument is present it is considered
rem                        to be new service name
rem
rem $Id: service.bat 1000718 2010-09-24 06:00:00Z mturk $
rem ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

rem ---------XAMPP-------------------------------------------------------------
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
::  Set JAVA_HOME or JRE_HOME     ::
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

echo.
echo [XAMPP]: Searching for JDK or JRE HOME with reg query ...
set JDKKeyName64=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit
set JDKKeyName32=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit
set JREKeyName64=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment
set JREKeyName32=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment

reg query "%JDKKeyName64%" /s
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 (
    echo . [XAMPP]: Could not find 32 bit or 64 bit JDK
    echo . [XAMPP]: Looking for 32 bit JDK on 64 bit machine
    goto FINDJDK32
)
set KeyName=%JDKKeyName64%
goto JDKRUN

:FINDJDK32
reg query "%JDKKeyName32%" /s
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU  1 (
    echo . [XAMPP]: Could not find 32 bit JDK
    echo . [XAMPP]: Looking for 32 bit or 64 bit JRE
    goto FINDJRE64
)
set KeyName=%JDKKeyName32%
goto JDKRUN

:FINDJRE64
reg query "%JREKeyName64%" /s
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 (
    echo . [XAMPP]: Could not find 32 bit or 64 bit JRE 
    echo . [XAMPP]: Looking for 32 bit JRE on 64 bit machine
    goto FINDJRE32
)
set KeyName=%JREKeyName64%
goto JRERUN

:FINDJRE32
reg query "%JREKeyName32%" /s
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 (
    echo . [XAMPP]: Could not find 32 bit JRE
    echo . [XAMPP]: Could not set JAVA_HOME or JRE_HOME. Aborting
    goto ENDERROR
)
set KeyName=%JREKeyName32%
goto JRERUN

:JDKRUN
echo.
echo [XAMPP]: Using JDK
set "CURRENT_DIR=%cd%"
set "CATALINA_HOME=%CURRENT_DIR%\tomcat"

set Cmd=reg query "%KeyName%" /s
for /f "tokens=2*" %%i in ('%Cmd% ^| find "JavaHome"') do set JAVA_HOME=%%j

echo.
echo [XAMPP]: Seems fine!
echo [XAMPP]: Set JAVA_HOME : %JAVA_HOME%
echo [XAMPP]: Set CATALINA_HOME : %CATALINA_HOME%
echo.

goto NEXT

:JRERUN
echo.
echo [XAMPP]: Using JRE
set "CURRENT_DIR=%cd%"
set "CATALINA_HOME=%CURRENT_DIR%\tomcat"

set Cmd=reg query "%KeyName%" /s
for /f "tokens=2*" %%i in ('%Cmd% ^| find "JavaHome"') do set JRE_HOME=%%j

echo.
echo [XAMPP]: Seems fine!
echo [XAMPP]: Set JRE_HOME : %JRE_HOME%
echo [XAMPP]: Set CATALINA_HOME : %CATALINA_HOME%
echo.

:ENDERROR
exit 1

:NEXT

echo [XAMPP]: Finding Java Version

set Cmd=reg query "%KeyName%" /v CurrentVersion
for /f "tokens=2*" %%i in ('%Cmd% ^| find "CurrentVersion"') do set CVERSION=%%j

echo [XAMPP]: Java Version: %CVERSION%
echo [XAMPP]: Starting Tomcat Service Install...
echo .

rem ----------END XAMPP-----------------------------------------------------------------

set "SELF=%~dp0%service.bat"
rem Guess CATALINA_HOME if not defined
set "CURRENT_DIR=%cd%"
if not "%CATALINA_HOME%" == "" goto gotHome
set "CATALINA_HOME=%cd%"
if exist "%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\tomcat7.exe" goto okHome
rem CD to the upper dir
cd ..
set "CATALINA_HOME=%cd%"
:gotHome
if exist "%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\tomcat7.exe" goto okHome
echo The tomcat.exe was not found...
echo The CATALINA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly.
echo This environment variable is needed to run this program
goto end
:okHome
rem Make sure prerequisite environment variables are set
if not "%JAVA_HOME%" == "" goto gotJdkHome
if not "%JRE_HOME%" == "" goto gotJreHome
echo Neither the JAVA_HOME nor the JRE_HOME environment variable is defined
echo Service will try to guess them from the registry.
goto okJavaHome
:gotJreHome
if not exist "%JRE_HOME%\bin\java.exe" goto noJavaHome
if not exist "%JRE_HOME%\bin\javaw.exe" goto noJavaHome
goto okJavaHome
:gotJdkHome
if not exist "%JAVA_HOME%\jre\bin\java.exe" goto noJavaHome
if not exist "%JAVA_HOME%\jre\bin\javaw.exe" goto noJavaHome
if not exist "%JAVA_HOME%\bin\javac.exe" goto noJavaHome
if not "%JRE_HOME%" == "" goto okJavaHome
set "JRE_HOME=%JAVA_HOME%\jre"
goto okJavaHome
:noJavaHome
echo The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly
echo This environment variable is needed to run this program
echo NB: JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE
goto end
:okJavaHome
if not "%CATALINA_BASE%" == "" goto gotBase
set "CATALINA_BASE=%CATALINA_HOME%"
:gotBase

set "EXECUTABLE=%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\tomcat7.exe"

rem Set default Service name
set SERVICE_NAME=Tomcat7
set PR_DISPLAYNAME=Apache Tomcat 7

if "x%1x" == "xx" goto displayUsage
set SERVICE_CMD=%1
shift
if "x%1x" == "xx" goto checkServiceCmd
:checkUser
if "x%1x" == "x/userx" goto runAsUser
if "x%1x" == "x--userx" goto runAsUser
set SERVICE_NAME=%1
set PR_DISPLAYNAME=Apache Tomcat %1
shift
if "x%1x" == "xx" goto checkServiceCmd
goto checkUser
:runAsUser
shift
if "x%1x" == "xx" goto displayUsage
set SERVICE_USER=%1
shift
runas /env /savecred /user:%SERVICE_USER% "%COMSPEC% /K \"%SELF%\" %SERVICE_CMD% %SERVICE_NAME%"
goto end
:checkServiceCmd
if /i %SERVICE_CMD% == install goto doInstall
if /i %SERVICE_CMD% == remove goto doRemove
if /i %SERVICE_CMD% == uninstall goto doRemove
echo Unknown parameter "%1"
:displayUsage
echo.
echo Usage: service.bat install/remove [service_name] [/user username]
goto end

:doRemove
rem Remove the service
"%EXECUTABLE%" //DS//%SERVICE_NAME%
if not errorlevel 1 goto removed
echo Failed removing '%SERVICE_NAME%' service
goto end
:removed
echo The service '%SERVICE_NAME%' has been removed
goto end

:doInstall
rem Install the service
echo Installing the service '%SERVICE_NAME%' ...
echo Using CATALINA_HOME:    "%CATALINA_HOME%"
echo Using CATALINA_BASE:    "%CATALINA_BASE%"
echo Using JAVA_HOME:        "%JAVA_HOME%"
echo Using JRE_HOME:         "%JRE_HOME%"

rem Use the environment variables as an example
rem Each command line option is prefixed with PR_

set PR_DESCRIPTION=Apache Tomcat 7.0.22 Server - http://tomcat.apache.org/
set "PR_INSTALL=%EXECUTABLE%"
set "PR_LOGPATH=%CATALINA_BASE%\logs"
set "PR_CLASSPATH=%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\bootstrap.jar;%CATALINA_BASE%\bin\tomcat-juli.jar;%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
rem Set the server jvm from JAVA_HOME
set "PR_JVM=%JRE_HOME%\bin\server\jvm.dll"
if exist "%PR_JVM%" goto foundJvm
rem Set the client jvm from JAVA_HOME
set "PR_JVM=%JRE_HOME%\bin\client\jvm.dll"
if exist "%PR_JVM%" goto foundJvm
set PR_JVM=auto
:foundJvm
echo Using JVM:              "%PR_JVM%"
"%EXECUTABLE%" //IS//%SERVICE_NAME% --StartClass org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap --StopClass org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap --StartParams start --StopParams stop --Startup auto
if not errorlevel 1 goto installed
echo Failed installing '%SERVICE_NAME%' service
goto ENDERROR
:installed
rem Clear the environment variables. They are not needed any more.
set PR_DISPLAYNAME=
set PR_DESCRIPTION=
set PR_INSTALL=
set PR_LOGPATH=
set PR_CLASSPATH=
set PR_JVM=
rem Set extra parameters
"%EXECUTABLE%" //US//%SERVICE_NAME% --JvmOptions "-Dcatalina.base=%CATALINA_BASE%;-Dcatalina.home=%CATALINA_HOME%;-Djava.endorsed.dirs=%CATALINA_HOME%\endorsed" --StartMode jvm --StopMode jvm
rem More extra parameters
set "PR_LOGPATH=%CATALINA_BASE%\logs"
set PR_STDOUTPUT=auto
set PR_STDERROR=auto

rem XAMPP: We need special parameters for Java 7
if "%CVERSION%" == "1.7" goto JAVA7
:JAVA
"%EXECUTABLE%" //US//%SERVICE_NAME% ++JvmOptions "-Djava.io.tmpdir=%CATALINA_BASE%\temp;-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager;-Djava.util.logging.config.file=%CATALINA_BASE%\conf\logging.properties" --JvmMs 128 --JvmMx 256
goto FINISH
:JAVA7
"%EXECUTABLE%" //US//%SERVICE_NAME% ++JvmOptions "-Djava.io.tmpdir=%CATALINA_BASE%\temp;-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager;-Djava.util.logging.config.file=%CATALINA_BASE%\conf\logging.properties;-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true" --JvmMs 128 --JvmMx 256
:FINISH
echo The service '%SERVICE_NAME%' has been installed.

:end
cd "%CURRENT_DIR%"
```